# Native Messaging: Failed to start native messaging host

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I downloaded the [native messaging example](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/nativeMessaging) which I'm trying to run without any changes but i get a error :

```
Failed to connect: Failed to start native messaging host.
```

Comment: Have you already read the documentation? I've listed several debugging tips at https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging#native-messaging-debugging

Comment: I have read this link! I'm sure I have sufficient permissions to execute the file! Have any other reason for this error?

Comment: Check the output of Chrome, see the first paragraph of the documentation that I've linked to see how to get useful information from Chrome.